# laravel prevent unauthenticated users from viewing the files

Tags: php, laravel

I want to try to make some route filter using pattern filter, but it's doesn't work. How to make a route to prevent unauthenticated users from viewing files on specific folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Route::get('/directory/{file}', array('before' => 'auth', function($file)
{
    return public_path() . "/directory/$file";
}));
```

Change `directory` to whatever the directory is you are trying to protect.  Also, I assumed the files you want to deal out are in your public directory.  That may need to be changed too, depending on your usage.

`Auth` is a filter that is already created in a default install of Laravel.  It just makes sure they aren't a "guest."  It will only let people access the directory if they are "logged in."  I believe it looks for a cookie that Laravel sets when you log someone in.

Comment: Thank you, i work with laravel 3 it's work if the file doesn't exist in the folder, but if the file is exist, it's doesn't work.